# How do vehicle critical hits work?

Tags: savage-worlds

On page 101 of Savage Worlds Deluxe is a table for critical hits when dealing with vehicles.  However, I can't find what would cause you to roll on this table.  How do critical hits on vehicles work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading *Vehicular Attacks, Damage* on page 110 of the *Explorer Edition* or page 100 of the *Deluxe Edition*, car damage works like this.

If you roll enough damage to "shake" a vehicle, it is not shaken, but instead forces the driver to make a Driving test or roll on the Out-Of-Control table.  A raise on the damage test actually wounds the vehicle giving all actions with the vehicle a -1 modifier.  Each wound also causes you to roll on the Critical Hits table.  The fourth wound wrecks the vehicle.

It can take a lot of damage to wreck a vehicle, but realise that going Out-Of-Control can completely remove a vehicle from play if you roll well on the table.  As a GM, I almost lost an aerial drone into the side of a building from an otherwise undamaging shot just last weekend.